# Alfresco exception message format

Tags: exception, alfresco

I want to show only my message for alfresco workflow exception. But in alfresco exception message format is that 
 **1. exception.class.name
 2. ErrorLogNumber 
 3. Message**

For example,
***org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowException: 05130007 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX***

I only want to show 3.Message not 1.exception.class.name and 2.ErrorLogNumber. I can remove ErrorLogNumber from message by adding a custom exception class. But I can't remove 1.exception.class.name from error message.
Let me know how to implement that.

Comment: Did you try fetching just the message with `getMessage()`, rather than calling `toString()` on the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple. Just throw `AlfrescoRuntimeException` with your message.

```
throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("your.message");
```

In that case you get a message, but loose exception subtyping.

It is really hard to explain in words how I was suprised when saw exception handling in alfresco javaScript code:

```
        onFormSubmitFailure: function FormManager_onFormSubmitFailure(response)
        {
           var failureMsg = null;
           if (response.json && response.json.message && response.json.message.indexOf("Failed to persist field 'prop_cm_name'") !== -1)
           {
                failureMsg = this.msg("message.details.failure.name");
           }
           else if (response.json && response.json.message && response.json.message.indexOf("PropertyValueSizeIsMoreMaxLengthException") !== -1)
           {
                failureMsg = this.msg("message.details.failure.more.max.length");
           }
           else if (response.json && response.json.message && response.json.message.indexOf("org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException") == 0)
           {  
              var split =  response.json.message.split(/(?:org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException:\s*\d*\s*)/ig);
              if (split && split[1])
              {
                    failureMsg = split[1];
              }
           }
           Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
           {
              title: this.msg(this.options.failureMessageKey),
              text: failureMsg ? failureMsg : (response.json && response.json.message ? response.json.message : this.msg("message.details.failure"))
           });
        },
```

As you can see they "catch" class name from java and replace it with message. I hope they provide more extensible way to handle custome exceptions.

**P.S.** Of course another way is to extend `alfresco.js` file and add one more `if else` condition for you exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override toString in your exception class? Or maybe to change logger implementation, if output is printed this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem as you and failed to trace where this message is created even using debugger, quite tricky. Also anyone on Alfresco forums couldn't help me. 
I developed a workaround instead of throwing an exception directly in java workflow task, I used a JS validation in form (the way I told you in another post), there I called a java webscript using ajax, which in case of error displayed JS alert box.